# Rails form to create/update receiving string and converting it to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, forms

I'm trying to create a form that accepts CSV strings like "pop, rock" and converts them to an array like ["pop", "rock"]. I'm using MongoDB to store them.

The CREATE is working great, but I'm having problems with the UPDATE part:

**-Problem 1:** When the tags field is filled I got

> ["pop", " rock"]

instead of

> pop, rock

**Problem 2:** Unpermitted parameters: tags error everytime I submit the form.

I want to be able to get a prefilled field with

> pop, rock

and be able to submit something like

> alternative, rock

Model (integral)

```
class Feed
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :id, type: String
  field :tags, type: Array
end
```

Form view (important part)

```
<%= f.label :tags %><br>
<%= f.text_field :tags%>
```

Controller (important parts)

```
      def create

        params[:feed][:tags] = params[:feed][:tags].split(',')
        @feed = Feed.new(feed_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @feed.save
            format.html { redirect_to @feed, notice: 'Feed was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @feed }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @feed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update

        respond_to do |format|
          if @feed.update(feed_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @feed, notice: 'Feed was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @feed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
      .
      .
      .
      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_feed
          @feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def feed_params
          params.require(:feed).permit(:title, :url, :id, :tags => [])
        end
```

This is the error I got:

```
Started PATCH "/feeds/54764080526f62251e050000" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-26 16:05:42 -0500
Processing by FeedsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5G1Z8P+Y9wS5bz8+5BdS9bIugFRxgOUBua0uHWU0THQ=", "feed"=>{"title"=>"Dropbox", "url"=>"http://dropbox.com", "id"=>"54764080526f62251e050000", "tags"=>"zzz, aaa"}, "commit"=>"Update Feed", "id"=>"54764080526f62251e050000"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=db_development collection=feeds selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54764080526f62251e050000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.4360ms
Unpermitted parameters: tags
Completed 302 Found in 4ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `["pop", " rock"]` because you have `field :tags, type: Array`.

As for the update error, you should post the error message you are getting.

Comment: What if you remove the `=> []` from your `feed_params` action?

Comment: If i remove the => [] I get problem on the Creation of a feed and the tags are not saved:


Started POST "/feeds" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-28 09:12:59 -0500
Processing by FeedsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5G1Z8P+Y9wS5bz8+5BdS9bIugFRxgOUBua0uHWU0THQ=", "feed"=>{"title"=>"test", "url"=>"test", "tags"=>"aaa,vvvv,zzz"}, "commit"=>"Create Feed"}
Unpermitted parameters: tags